# how to add additional message in a Drupal form

Tags: drupal, drupal-forms

I would like to additional instructions to a custom Drupal form, similar to hook_help, but at the bottom of the form. Is there a function or hook available for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add an element to the form with no type, its' value will be displayed as HTML on the page.

See [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html#markup)

```
$form['contact_information'] = array(
  '#value' => t('You can leave us a message using the contact form below.'),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

theming forms: http://www.lullabot.com/articles/modifying-forms-drupal-5-and-6

you can cck or other modules...